# Editing struct using function

Tags: c

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int salary;
    int experience;
} employee_t;
```

and a main function:

```
void main()
{
    employee_t newEmployee={"",0,0}, tmp;

    newEmployee = readEmployee( &tmp ); //input for 5 employee's    
    printf("Employee name is %s, salary is %d, experience is %d years\n", newEmployee.name, newEmployee.salary, newEmployee.experience);
}
```

and another function:

```
employee_t readEmployee(employee_t* emp)
{
    employee_t tmp;
    char name[MAX_SIZE];

    printf("Please enter Employee's name:(max %d chars)", 19);
    scanf("%s",&tmp.name);

    printf("Please enter Employee's salary:");
    scanf("%s",&tmp.salary);

    printf("Please enter Employee's experience:"); 
    scanf("%s",&tmp.experience);

    return tmp;
}
```

I want to modify my struct in this function and return the updated struct. When I do it the function doesn't return anything (prints nothing in my main).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for a start - you use %s to scanf into salary and experience which are integers. So you got memory overrun there.

Comment: What is the point of passing `emp` to the function? It is unused.

Comment: 'employee_t* readEmployee(employee_t* emp)
{
 employee_t* tmp;
 char name[MAX_SIZE];

 printf("Please enter Employee's name:(max %d chars)", 19);
 //scanf("%s",&emp->name);
 scanf("%s",&tmp->name);

    printf("Please enter Employee's salary:");
    //scanf("%d",&emp->salary);
 scanf("%d",&tmp->salary);

    printf("Please enter Employee's experience:");
    //scanf("%d",&emp->experience);   
 scanf("%d",&tmp->experience);

 emp = tmp;

 return emp;
}'
its still not working, and i changed the %s to %d

Comment: What's your input and what output are you getting?  Also, post your updated code in your question so that it's readable.

Comment: don't use raw scanf. use fgets to read a string into a buffer and then use sscanf. it saves a lot of grief.

Comment: @Coder123 yo've got it wrong again, the version in your comment returns a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the function and you get undefined behaviour. Just replace the `scanf` in the program as it is in your question and it works.

Comment: the user enters the input, e.g:( "employee",12000,3)
the output is blank.
name=,salary= ,expirience=

Comment: @Tom Tanner i changed it like you said, but the main is still wrong, it doesnt accept (&tmp)

Comment: @Coder123 "it"? what it? doesn't accept (&tmp) how?

Comment: visual studio give me an error "no suitable constructor exists to convert from *employee_t* to Employee"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. But you have to be careful with reading a string using `scanf()`. It can cause a buffer overflow.

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int salary;
    int experience;
} employee_t;

employee_t *readEmployee(employee_t *emp)
{
    printf("Please enter Employee's name:(max 19 chars)");
    scanf("%s", emp->name); // -> operator

    printf("Please enter Employee's salary:");
    scanf("%d", &emp->salary); // %d

    printf("Please enter Employee's experience:"); 
    scanf("%d",&emp->experience);

    return emp;
}

int main(void) {
    employee_t *newEmployee, tmp; // newEmployee is now a pointer

    newEmployee = readEmployee( &tmp ); // newEmployee now points to tmp    
    printf("Employee name is %s, salary is %d, experience is %d years\n", newEmployee->name, newEmployee->salary, newEmployee->experience);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i cant read the tmp employee here:
in this line:
"newEmployee = readEmployee( &tmp ); "

Comment: @Coder123 What do you mean by that?

Comment: something wrong with the syntex of this line (in main), i cant init my newEmployee and pass &tmp in the readEmployee function

Comment: There are no syntax errors. I compiled this code successfully using GCC (without any warnings). The program works as expected.

Comment: wired... it writes: 
"IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "employee_t *" to "Employee"
in visual studio 2010 :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf`s  are wrong. Replace them like this:

```
scanf("%s",tmp.name);

scanf("%d",&tmp.salary);

scanf("%d",&tmp.experience);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format specifiers in your `scanf` calls when reading in the salary and experience.  Those fields are of type `int`, so you should be using the `%d` format specifier.